# create pl sql trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a Trigger for `before insert` to validate a case date.
The case date should be between 5 years before and 7 years after current date.

For example, in 2018 the case date should be from year 2013 to 2025. If the  date is out of range the trigger should stop inserting data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ch
BEFORE INSERT 
on CASE
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE

    CASN number;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO CASN
    FROM CASE
    WHERE :new.STARTDATE > SYSDATE;
    IF (CASN > 0) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Start DATE CANNOT Be GREATER than today's 
date');
END IF; 
END;
```

Here `STARTDATE`  is column of `CASE` table

This trigger starts when start date is greater than today's date but I need it to run when it's out range as given above.

How do I add an specified interval to the sysdate, so that it could work for the above condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic you are using in your `Trigger` is completely wrong. You don't need to get the count from the table using `:NEW.STARTDATE`. This is something what you are looking for.

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER ch
  BEFORE INSERT ON cases
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( :NEW.casedate < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' year
         OR :NEW.casedate > SYSDATE + INTERVAL '7' year ) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
'CASE DATE should be in range: current date - 5 years and current date + 7 years')
;
END IF;
END;

/
```

**EDIT** : I have not added `TRUNC` on the dates because I'm not sure if you want to consider time component as well while considering date range.If you are ok with just considering days, you may use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` in place of  just `SYSDATE`. Modify it accordingly as per your business needs.

Another option is to use `CHECK` constraint. Although Oracle does not allow you to have
use `SYSDATE`  in a check constraint definition, you may create another column( or reuse existing) that defaults to `SYSDATE` and apply check constraint on that.

```
ALTER TABLE CASES ADD ( CURR_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE );

ALTER TABLE CASES ADD CONSTRAINT
RANGE_CHECK CHECK( casedate > CURR_DATE - INTERVAL '5' YEAR
                   AND casedate < CURR_DATE + INTERVAL '7' YEAR) ENABLE;
```

Comment: It is common for tables to have a metadata column such as DATE_CREATED to track the history of the record. We could use such a column in the check constraint. Also, it might be a good idea to truncate the dates (certainly the `sysdate` in the lower bound) to prevent the time element failing an apparently valid date.

Comment: @APC : Thanks. I've added a note in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Date arithmetic. Oracle Database enables you to perform arithmetic operations on dates and time stamps in several ways:

Add a numeric value to or subtract it from a date, as in SYSDATE + 7; Oracle Database treats the number as the number of days.

Add one date to or subtract it from another, as in l_hiredate - SYSDATE.
Use a built-in function to “move” a date by a specified number of months or to another date in a week.

Here are some examples of date arithmetic with a date and a number (assume in all cases that the l_date variable has been declared as DATE):

```
Set a local variable to tomorrow’s date: 



l_date := SYSDATE + 1;


Move back one hour:



l_date := SYSDATE - 1/24;


Move ahead 10 seconds:



l_date := SYSDATE + 10 / (60 * 60 * 24);
```

When you add one date to or subtract it from another, the result is the number of days between the two. As a result, executing this block:

```
    DECLARE
       l_date1   DATE := SYSDATE;
       l_date2   DATE := SYSDATE + 10;
    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
          l_date2 - l_date1);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
          l_date1 - l_date2);
    END;
```

returns the following output:

10
-10

Comment: It's OK to post contents from another website, but you must also give it due credit : Add a reference to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12plsql-1408561.html

Comment: @KaushikNayak - actually I don't think it is acceptable to construct an answer by a wholesale cut'n'paste from another site, especailly as its original author does respond to questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I just tried to help him...........a code is better understood if u write it by urself and not when u copy paste it from stackoverflow @APC

Comment: Cut'n'pasting another person's work (verbatim and unacknowledged) seems an odd way to to encourage someone to write their own code. Besides which, this answer does not address the OP's actual concerns. It would have been better if you had actually written a proper answer focused on the question, as KaushikNayak did.

Comment: It might not encourage u...but for me, getting some more of information always helps me to try some coding on my own

Comment: Anuj, I understand your thoughts. But, there are certain standards maintained by answers in this site unlike any other technical forums on the internet. Your answer may be good but definitely not helpful. So, to avoid further downvotes and Facebook style comments and arguments, I would suggest you delete this answer. No grudges pal..have a wonderful day...